# About $x(\ln(x\ln(x))-1)<p_x<x\ln(x\ln(x)), x>5$ and better results

Tags: prime-numbers

I need some tips about this:

It has been proved that

**(1)** $$x(\ln(x\ln(x))-1)<p_x<x\ln(x\ln(x)),\quad x>5$$

Is there a better results?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use either `\cdot` or nothing at all rather than `*` for multiplication next time. Also note that `\ln x` or `\ln (x)` produces nicer results ($ln(x)$ versus $\ln(x)$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pierre Dusart has improved these estimates in several papers, e.g. [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0442), 2010. Proposition $6.6$ states that for $k\ge 688383$ we have
$$
p_k\le k\left( \log k +\log_2 k -1 +\frac{\log_2 k-2.0}{\log k}\right);
$$
and in Proposition $6.7$ it is stated that for all $k\ge 3$ we have
$$
p_k\ge k\left( \log k +\log_2 k -1 +\frac{\log_2 k-2.1}{\log k}\right).
$$
Here $\log_2 x$ means $\log(\log(x))$.

Comment: Should be spelled Dusart :)

Comment: Yes, of course - thank you.

Comment: thanks, this helped me a lot!